# Laravel variable to img with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am returning a base64 string from controller to view.
The base64 is correct I checked it online (base64string to image ...)
In my javascript I call it like this:

```
<script>
    var crosshairImgString = {!! $crosshairPathString !!};
</script>
```

The string contains an Image which I want to Center on a canvas.
I try putting it inside an image tag's src like this:

```
centerImageAtCanvas();
function centerImageAtCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    var image = new Image();
    console.log(crosshairImgString);
    image.src = {{ $crosshairPathString }};
    image.onload = function () {
        var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
        cxt.drawImage(image,
             canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,
             canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2
        );
    };
}
```

but I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

which references to this part:

```
var crosshairImgString = data:image/png;base64,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;
```

Comment: write `var crosshairImgString = '{!! $crosshairPathString !!}'` in assigning variable

Comment: Quotes are required while assigning value to variable for string when using php variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, just a small error:
I am returning a base64 string from controller to view.
The base64 is correct I checked it online (base64string to image ...)
In my javascript I call it like this:

```
<script>
    var crosshairImgString = '{!! $crosshairPathString !!}';
</script>
```

which will result into something like:

```
var crosshairImgString = 'data:image/png;base64,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';


centerImageAtCanvas();
function centerImageAtCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    var image = new Image();
    console.log(crosshairImgString);
    image.src = '{{ $crosshairPathString }}';
    image.onload = function () {
        var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
        cxt.drawImage(image,
             canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,
             canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: hi the first error disappeared but the Image still does not Show up any idea?

Comment: I have updated the code, also please let me know where are you assigning that variable to "src" of image.

Comment: edit: note the change `image.src = '{{ $crosshairPathString }}';` in the script